# Independence of two random variables Y/X and X

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, conditional-probability

> Consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that X ∼ U(0, 1)
>   and $Y|X=x$ ∼ N($x$, $x^2$), where $U$ and $N$ denotes an Uniform and Normal distributions, respectively. Prove that $Y/X$ and $X$ are independent.

I tried using the variable change method, but $X,Y$ are not independent (cov($X,Y$) is not $0$). As they are independent, I can't simply multiply their pdf's to get the joint pdf. So, I can't proceed further using this method. Can anyone help me in proving this?

Comment: Actually the distributions of them are not necessary information here. All you need is $f_{X,Y}(x, y) = f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)$ - the joint pdf is equal to the product of the corresponding conditional pdf and marginal pdf.

Comment: @BGM but X and Y are not independent. So how can we write it?

Comment: The conditional pdf here can be viewed as a marginal pdf, so when the joint pdf is equal to the product of the two corresponding marginal pdf, then they are independent.

Comment: @BGM I'm sorry, I couldn't get you. X,Y are not independent. So, how can we write that $f_{X,Y}(x, y) = f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)$ ? Isn't the joint pdf= product of marginal pdf's when the two random variables are independent. Can you try to write it in the solution clearly. Thanks!

Comment: The equation here is always true whenever those pdfs exist. This is the definition of the condtional pdf.

Comment: @BGM Yeah thanks! Got it after thinking for a while. Small miscommunication between us.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to prove this is through characteristic functions. We have $E(e^{itY}|X)=e^{itX}e^{-t^{2}X^{2}/2}$. Replace $t$ by $\frac t X$ to get $E(e^{it\frac Y X}|X)=e^{it}e^{-t^{2}/2}$. Now consider $Ee^{it\frac Y X +isX}$. We have $E(e^{it\frac Y X +isX}|X)=e^{it}e^{-t^{2}/2}e^{isX}$. Take expectation to get $Ee^{it\frac Y X +isX}=e^{it}e^{-t^{2}/2}Ee^{isX}$. The fact that the joint characteristic function of $\frac Y X$ and $X$ at $(t,s)$ is the product of a function of $t$ and a function  of $s$ implies that these two variables are independent. Note that the distribution of $X$ plays no role.